# Log an agent into switch using CM and AES with DMCC .net API

Tags: avaya

I am very new to CTI applications and I am learning and implementing an application using DMCC .NET api. 
I apologize for my very limited understanding of the whole DMCC and CTI stuff. I basically want my application to log an agent into an extension when the agent provides a login, password and an extension number. Can I do this using DMCC? I found a serviceProvider.getThirdPartyCallController.SetAgentState() method that seems to do this, but it does not require an extension id anywhere. my workflow is something like when an agent comes in for his/her shift, they would log in into my application with the agentID, password and extension number and my application would automatically log them in. Is this possible using DMCC? Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log the agent in with dialing the feature access code.

You can check what your login FAC is using SAT command 'display feature-access-codes' and look for AGENT WORK MODES on the 5th page. You should use the FAC for 'Login Access Code'.

Dial string: LOGIN_FAC AGENT_CODE

Or if you have the login function assigned to a button on the phone then you can use the DMCC push button funcionality to log the agent in.

[Dashboard](https://www.devconnectprogram.com/site/global/products_resources/avaya_aura_application_enablement_services/interfaces/dmcc/development_tools_configurations/dmcc_dashboard/index.gsp)